# How to declare object variables for good code structure objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I know my question is silly but I need to know this for my further development. I am developing my `iPhone application` programmatically without using any `xib and storyboard`, for that i have declared multiple `object variables` like below

```
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
    UIImageView *splashImage;
    NSTimer *checkJSONtimer;
    UILocalNotification *localNotification;
    NSUserDefaults * defaults;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Login *loginView;
@end
```

Above code Into `.h file` I had declared, Now my question is some of the `UIObjects declared` without `@property` and some `variable` we are declaring with `properties` and `attributes` also. Which `Objects UI and NS` , how to declare by above two methods.

Which one is proper way of `programming` and good too?.

Comment: Oh no.  That really is bad.  Does it actually build without duplicate symbol linker errors?

Comment: You realize you are creating global variables each time your header file is included?

Comment: Sorry I cant get you. give me one good explanation with code its better to understand new developers@trojanfoe

Comment: Your question is too broad.  There is so much to cover that you don't understand.

Comment: Just tell me what is the diffrences with @property and without. which objects , how to declare that one. plz give some examples. thats enough@trojanfoe

Comment: and moreover I have created all my button event methods - (void)button click:... like its good or bad. how to declare that one If I want to create programmatically my app.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should read the documentation.. But the very short answer is that properties give you getters and setters for free. (BUT PLEASE READ THE DOCS, there is a lot more to it than just that and possible) When you define @property you don't have to define the variable anymore (in the past you had to actually). Usually you want just want to use properties.

Answer (score 0):

To the comments:

There is little reason to declare ivars (instance variables, that what you called object variables) in the header. It has been necessary in the past (years ago), but isn't. On the other side declared properties (`@property`) adds semantic information to the user of the class' API.

So in your interface there should be no ivars at all.

However, there are some reasons to declare ivars explicitly after declaring a declared property. You should do this in a class continuation (extension) like so:

```
@interface MyClass()
{
  id _ivar;
}
```

I prefer to declare ivars in the implementation, whenever it is possible. (Most developer do not know about this ability.)

```
@implementation MyClass
{
  id _ivar;
}
```

If the identifier of the ivar matches the identifier of the declared property plus _, the generated code will use that ivar in both variants.

Comment: What about UIObjects?

Comment: He's not declaring iVars but globals due to the lack of braces!

Comment: Yes...I know that one..But my question is simple how to declare UIObjects? with property or without property

Comment: @AnswerMe I do not know that there is something special with UI objects. Please read the documentation about the strength of the references.

Comment: @Macmade I'm not sure about that because it is only a snippet and the lines are indented. However, my answer tells him how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In the Header file *.h, you should place global properties, the one's you want to access from other classes when you instantiate your object class. You should use @property for that.

If you want local object properties just place your @property inside @interface in the *.m file:

```
@interface Class()
@property NSTimer *yourTimer;
@end
```

For object local variables you can place them inside @implementation in the *.m file:

```
@implementation Class {
    int timeToWaitInMillisseconds;
}
```

Further reading: http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/properties

Comment: For  UIImageView *splashImage; this one?

Comment: In the header there should only be an `extern` declaration. However, you shouldn't call them "global properties", because properties belong to something.